# Appcelerator: Using Subview Percent Heights, Parent is Not Filled

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a custom iOS header and footer of 60dp and 40dp height respectively.  In the remaining area that I call the body, I add 5 subviews each with 20% height and a different non-white background color.  I end up with a white gap after the last subview and above the footer.  Using 1 subview with 100% height or 2 subviews with 50% height each, there is no gap.  Therefore I'm assuming this is caused by rounding.  How can I resolve this and continue to use percents?

Comment: can you please hare some code.

Comment: yes I also saw a hairline gap(around 2dp) at the bottom but only in case of vertical layout.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well and created an issue:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19900

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to not use explicit heights. Instead, place the elements between specific percentage based tops and bottoms. So if you have 5 views, place the first at `top: '0%', bottom: '80%'`. (That *should* be equivalent to `top: '0%', height: '20%'`, but with apparent rounding errors, it isn't...) Then the next at `top: '20%', bottom: '60%'`. Continue on to place the last 3 views. They will appear one on top of the other. (Because the rounding errors will counteract each other, you won't have any gaps.)

Here is an example of this in action:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: 'red'
});

win.add(/*header*/Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 0,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}));

var content = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 60, bottom: 40,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL
});
var childCount = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    content.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'Child ' + (i + 1),
        width: Ti.UI.FILL,
        top: (20 * i) + '%', // 0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%
        bottom: (20 * (childCount - 1 - i)) + '%', // 80%, 60%, 40%, 20%, 0%
        backgroundColor: 'gray'
    }));
}
win.add(content);

win.add(/*footer*/Ti.UI.createView({
    bottom: 0,
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
}));

win.open();
```